# How is it possible price on Coinbase drops below my Limit Order when it is only partially filled?

Tags: coinbase.com, ethereum

I had a post only limit order place for €172 per ETH, about 50% of the order filled before the price dropped to €171.95, leaving my limit order somehow still open? The order was placed when the price was above €172 so didn't execute as a market order at any point.

This has happened several times on Coinbase Pro, surely the point of a limit order is to the keep the order on the book, so why is the price skipping my order?

Comment: IMHO, this topic belongs to bitcoin SE. In short, cryptocurrency exchange is **not** regulated, so any answer on how it fulfils the order is highly speculated and opinion-based. It doesn't work like forex trading nor like the stock exchange.

Comment: Its really more to do with Limit Orders rather than whatever the underlying asset is.

Comment: Nice edit but Coinbase is regulated as an exchange so its not speculative and opinion based..

Comment: Quick question: were you placing the order to *buy* ETH? That seems to be the case from the details in your question, but it wasn't stated explicitly.

Comment: Yes was a buy order

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a private exchange that may follow different rules

Comment: This appears to be offtopic for bitcoin stackexchange too, not least because Ethereum is not Bitcoin. A question about how Coinbase operate should be directed to them first, I feel; failing that https://www.reddit.com/r/CoinBase/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/ both have significantly broader readership more likely than we to have an answer for OP.